# Use MS Graph API and Postman to call Teams, Unsupported AAD Identity

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I tried to create a call in Teams trough Microsoft Graph Api. I created a  App with the given permissions but when i try to do the POST on: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/calls` i get this error:

```json
    {
        "error": {
            "code": "UnknownError",
            "message": "{\"errorCode\":\"7500\",\"message\":\"Unsupported AAD Identity.\",\"instanceAnnotations\":[]}",
            "innerError": {
                "date": "2020-11-11T14:38:43",
                "request-id": "74ee843f-ba7e-4d87-b1e2-617c6fdce77c",
                "client-request-id": "74ee843f-ba7e-4d87-b1e2-617c6fdce77c"
            }
        }
    }
```

Token and everything looks good. If I change the token I get another error that this one is wrong.

To be honest my knowledge about Azure etc. is very low.

Comment: Create calls doesn't support delegated permissions(User token). Please get App only token using client crediential flow having [Application permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions). Then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

What Shiva said is right. You may have used a user token to call the API, so an error occurred. The  [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) call currently only supports application tokens. You need to grant `application permissions` to the application and use the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to obtain Token.

[image]